# Use URI to get Bitmap in Another Activity

Tags: android, image, android-intent, kotlin, uri

I have got the `URI` of an Image in an Activity for example: `ImageActivity` and set the `URI` to an object named `Item`.

```
val item = Item()
item.imageURI = uri
```

Now, I have got the returned result from `ImageActivity` to for example: `UploadActivity`.

Now, I want to upload the `Item` object that I got from `ImageActivity` from `UploadActivity`. I am uploading the image by encoding the `Bitmap` of the image to `Base64`. So, I need the `Bitmap` of the image.

I got that by this:

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, item.imageURI)
item.itemImage = imageToString(bitmap)
```

But it is showing error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord
```

How to solve this? Please elaborate on your answer as much as possible.

Comment: Where did the `Uri` come from? Where did you get its value?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have mentioned it in the question. I am getting the `URI` from `ImageActivity`. There is an `ImageView` and I am getting this `URI` on `onActivityResult` method with this code:

`val uri = data?.data`

Comment: "I am getting the URI from ImageActivity" -- and where is `ImageActivity` getting it from? "I am getting this URI on onActivityResult method with this code: val uri = data?.data" -- and what request is triggering this `onActivityResult()` call?

Comment: @CommonsWare Though I hardly think it is relevant to my question, I am getting this image from `Gallery` with `onClickListener` on `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting this image from Gallery

I am going to interpret this as meaning that you are using an `Intent` like `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_PICK`.

If so, then by default, [the only place that `Uri` can be used is in the activity instance that receives it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) (`ImageActivity` in your case).

Your options include:

- Get rid of `UploadActivity` and do something else. For example, you could have the actual uploading be performed by a repository, with the UI handled by `ImageActivity` (directly, via fragments, etc.).
- Pass the `Uri` to `UploadActivity` via the "data" facet of an `Intent`, plus include `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on that `Intent`

That second option would look something like:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java).setData(yourUri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION))
```

(where `yourUri` is your `Uri`)

Comment: I can't follow your suggestion number one cause I have an `Item` array in `UploadActivity` which are in a `RecyclerView` and I want to upload all items in the `RecyclerView` at once.

Comment: Now, regarding second one, I tried this - 
`val resultCode = 101
                val resultIntent = Intent()
                resultIntent.setData(eachItem.imageURI)
                resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
                resultIntent.putExtra("eachItem", eachItem)
                setResult(resultCode, resultIntent)
                finish()`

Comment: And in the `UploadActivity`, I used this -
`val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, data.data)
                    eachItem.itemImage = CommonMethods().imageToString(bitmap)`

And receiving this error -

`java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10184 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2Fdownload%2FToys-Hub-Pre-School.png`